# Executable from Google App Engine project

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to create an executable file from a Google App engine project in Python?

Comment: what is 'executable'? You can create any file, and add `execute` permision after download (`chmod 755`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... no. But there are open-source projects available that allow you to run your App Engine application locally, and that attempt to be compatible with Google's App Engine API.

For example, check out typhoonae: 
http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/

You could develop your application using the Google SDK, and then deploy it on a local machine using the TyphoonAE app server.